# Navigation Nodes in django-cms example

Tags: django, navigation, django-cms, django-mptt

Can you give me an example how can i use Navigation Nodes?

Cannot find examples in [documentation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.2/getting_started/navigation.html#properties-of-navigation-nodes-in-templates).

There is this `{{ node }}` but where is it coming from?

Particalarly i am intereisted in `{{ node.is_leaf_node }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each navigation node is simply a link/entry in your menu tree so they are generated from your page layout, for example:

```
- Home
  - About
  - Projects
    - Project A
    - Project B
  - Contact
```

creates a menu with each page representing a node in the menu tree.

There's an example of them working in [the default `menu.html` template](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templates/menu/menu.html) (where `child` is a node in the menu):

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %}
<li class="{% if child.selected %}selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %}sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %}descendant{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    {% if child.children %}
    <ul>
        {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I also found that but I am interested in `{{ node.is_leaf_node }}`

Comment: It's [a term from MPTT](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/mptt.models.html#mptt.models.MPTTModel.is_leaf_node). It simply means that the node/menu-link has no children (like About & Contact above in the example)

Comment: If I am in Contact, how can i know if `{{ this_node.is_leaf_node }}`?

Comment: because it won't have any links to any other node. The menu is implemented via MPTT which is a tree-like data structure where every node has a relationship with it's parents & children so it knows where it is in relation to the other nodes

Comment: The thing I am trying to achive is to show_submenu if page has children and to show sibblings if it has no children. And boy I am stuck here!!

Comment: I solved that by creating custom tag and traversing children by my own.